# Draw a circle using blob KineticJs

Tags: javascript, canvas, blob, kineticjs, geometry

Please help!

Is it possible to create a perfect circle using blob? I'm using blob to create irregular shapes and then I tween them but my last shape should be a perfect circle. I'm having trouble creating perfect circle with blob. I'm using KineticJs by the way. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to create a perfectly circular blob.

A KineticJS blob is a series of Cubic Bezier curves.  Those kinds of curves cannot form a perfect circle.

Comment: Hi Thanks for you answer. Good thing I had a backup plan. :) I actually have another question that is related to this one, maybe you can help?

Comment: Here's the link to my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552372/tween-multiple-blobs-in-kineticjs